# How to generate human like mouse pointer movement using Fitt's Law

Tags: java, machine-learning, mouseevent

I was trying to generate the human like mouse movement. While finding the correct model I come to know about [Fitts's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts%27s_law). 
You can read more about the law and the reason behind the mathematical model of it [here](https://hcibook.com/e3/text//online/fitts-cybernetic). I want to generate the human like mouse pointer data given distance between source to target and width of target object[image: m].

I am not able to come up with the good model to find the radius of circle of error and position and number of circle of error explained in the below image.

Also I am planning to use [Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) to achieve random curves in intermediate stages.

I believe the solution of the problem contains following steps

1) Find out the time going to take for the whole interaction, (after removing some initial extra waiting time ) using Fitts's Law.

2) Based on time and distance find the number of circle of error, and using that number also find the decreasing radius of each circle. One of the possible approach is to use log function.

3) Find out position of each circle which is random but still in the intended direction. This is one of the most confusing task. There are many possibilities but there is few particular model behind where circle of errors are placed.

4) Find out the random points inside the circle but still in intended direction.

5) Pass the (Time, X,Y) triplets to MouseMove function of selenium

I am not sure how to achieve step 3,4 and 5.

Preferred language to achieve this is Java using selenium.

Comment: I want to do it using java and selenium. I understand that it is not related to programming language but my requirement is specific to java.

Comment: if you want most awesome explanation of Fitts' Law you can refer to this link. Its most clear explanation ever. https://timmarco.com/fitts/